# Would the Green New Deal cost 600k per household?

Tags: united-states

[A recent Fox News report](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/green-new-deal-would-cost-93-trillion-or-600g-per-household-study-says?spot_im_reply_id=sp_ANQXRpqH_urn%243Auri%243Abase64%243Af1ab8b6b-6db9-50e7-993f-8085685dda2f_c_Dt1tYN_r_wyjf6K&spot_im_highlight_immediate=true#) uses numbers provided by a self-proclaimed "center-right" American [organization](https://www.americanactionforum.org/research/the-green-new-deal-scope-scale-and-implications/) which details the predicted costs of the Green New Deal, totaling up to 93 trillion dollars, or 600k per household.

This is more than 4 times the current total national debt of the US, so I'm skeptical of the numbers provided. Are these numbers correct after all, or is there another source that gives 'more rational' numbers?

Comment: Of that $93 trillion, [most of the projected cost](https://www.americanactionforum.org/research/the-green-new-deal-scope-scale-and-implications/) is from universal healthcare ($36 trillion over 10 years) and jobs guarantee/universal basic income (up to $44 trillion). It's not clear that those will make it into whatever version comes up for vote.

Comment: "Costing" how? Over what time frame? Compared to which alternatives? There's [costs involved in not taking action](https://www.nrdc.org/sites/default/files/cost.pdf) as well (just tossing that in, that's not the "one number" I would pitch against this claim). So "correct" or "rational" (aside from being two very different things) is very much up to definition of terms. Can you clarify what *exactly* you're asking?

Comment: @ff524 I had seen that Universal Healthcare was meant to save taxpayers money, and I'd have expected that jobs/universal basic income would increase tax revenue substantially and/or improve the economy, so those would also be important factors to note in an answer.

Comment: @DevSolar I don't see why any costs from a lack of action couldn't be included in any tallying of net cost. It ought to be the responsibility of any news network to at least try to take into account all of the different impacting factors, so if something like that was left out of Fox News' reporting that would be good to have noted in any answer for this question.

Comment: I will *not* attempt to tackle a spreadsheet calculating "total costs of this vs. that", because this is about *global* economic predictions (i.e. inherently inaccurate and speculative). I was looking at whether you'd be willing to reduce a work that would keep a government task force busy for several years down to something manageable in a Skeptics.SE answer.

Comment: @DevSolar If something is inherently inaccurate or speculative, then the alternative that could be provided in any answer is simply stating as much. It seemed to me from reading other answers that this was fairly standard practice on Skeptics.SE?

Comment: It's also unfortunately standard practice on Skeptics.SE to A) post a diffuse claim, and then B) attack any answer on basis of it being just as diffuse by necessity. And the question is *humungous* in scope (and, personally, I'd not consider it worthy of my time simply because of who's making the claim).

Comment: @DevSolar I can certainly understand the fear, but it's not something I would ever do. If the best answer available to answer a question is really "Nobody is really sure, and the article is just speculation. Here's some other studies that contradict the article, support it, or provide details" then that's the best answer available. You have a fair point about the source in particular, but it's one that's very popular and having an answer here about that article would be very helpful for many people I think.

Comment: People complain about how expensive universal health care would be but they always fail to mention how much the current system costs which should raise a lot of red flags. If universal health care was really more expensive it should be easy to point to numbers to show it. I personally feel that the objections are from the rich people in charge of the systems being afraid that they will lose income from the changes.

Comment: @JoeW: I object to government-controlled healthcare on the basis of something much more important than prices: advances in medicine. The argument that we shouldn't pay 5x the price for care that is perhaps 2-3 years ahead of single-payer systems fails to understand mathematical induction. 2017 care is not much worse than 2019 care. But if society chooses to save the money and have 2017 care in 2019, then when 2021 rolls around and your choice results in 2019 care, what you really mean is 2017 care because that's what 2019 used. And in 2045, you'll still have care developed in 2017. Not good.

Comment: @BenVoigt You do realize that the US government funds a massive amount of medical research each year?

Comment: @JoeW: Basic research.  Without the commercial component there would be much much less applied research and actual effect on practice.

Comment: @BenVoigt "And in 2045, you'll still have care developed in 2017" <-- is this a zeno's paradox kind of thing?

Comment: @Avery: The form of the argument is similar, but while Zeno's is invalid because it resorts to infinitesimals, this argument works with steps that don't converge to zero.

Comment: @BenVoigt I will point out that when you have a system that raises the price on a drug which was created over a century ago or another one that was fully funded by the government over 50 years ago you might have a problem with an industry that can't properly control prices.

Comment: @JoeW: "raises the price on a drug which was created over a century ago" -- it's perfectly normal for nominal prices to rise at the rate of inflation.  Do you have a specific claim concerning increases in real (inflation-corrected) prices?  Are you aware that drug patents in the USA do expire?

Comment: @BenVoigt So when Insulin has increased in price by over 300% and the epipen by over 400% in recent years that is due to inflation? Also just because a patent as expired it doesn't mean that people are making competitors to the drug. I would also question why drugs are so much cheaper in Canada.

Comment: @JoeW: Neither of those are true in any meaningful way. For one thing, the price of the drug invented 100 years ago is down. ["Prices of Novolin and Humulin (traditional short- and intermediate-acting insulins) have turned south, while prices of modern rapid- and long-acting insulins continue to go up. On average, traditional insulins now cost less than half of what modern insulins cost."](https://www.goodrx.com/blog/how-much-does-insulin-cost-compare-brands/) If there are large profits, competitors will appear. The expensive forms of insulin are still under patent, only exist thanks to profit

Comment: 600k per household divided by 80 years lifetime divided by 12 month is _60 $ per month_ per household. How much does your household pay for medical insurance?

Comment: @ff524 - thanks for the basic check on the numbers. If they count that $36 T in universal healthcare as an increase per household, when it actually represents a savings per household ($36T more in ***government*** healthcare spending, which is offset by removing the need to current *private* spending, which would be projected to be more), then we know the numbers are just hysterical nonsense.

Comment: @Aganju & Polo, Their website specifies that the cost (under section D) would be for 2020-2029, not 80 years. But your point does still stand even with that, I believe.